# Display custom reference in magento 2

Tags: layout, magento-2.0

I have added a custom reference in 1 column xml (`app\design\frontend\Companyname\theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout`) by following manner to display custom section.

```
<container name="home.slider" as="slider" after="global.notices" htmlTag="section" htmlId="slider" />
```

But custom html section is not displaying. Although I have added a custom block with following code and that is working fine.

```
<container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" before="main.content" htmlId="header">
        <block name="header.top" as="header.top" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  template="Magento_Theme::html/header/top.phtml"  before="-" />
</container>
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here or is there any other method by which we can display custom reference.

Following is the complete code of `1column.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" before="main.content" htmlId="header">
        <block name="header.top" as="header.top" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  template="Magento_Theme::html/header/top.phtml"  before="-" />
    </container>
    <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
    <container name="home.slider" as="slider" after="global.notices" htmlTag="section" htmlId="slider" />
   <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" htmlId="footer" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: plz show your xml full code

Comment: @rakesh I have modified the question